# Angular 2 cannot find module d3-cloud

Tags: d3.js, angular, systemjs

For my angular 2 app with typescript, Im using systemjs for modules and grunt for build
In systemJsconfig file Im loading
map :{
.....
'd3': 'npm:d3/build/d3.js',
'd3-cloud' : 'npm:d3-cloud',
}
In my component:
importing the d3 and d3-cloud
import * as D3 from 'd3';
import * as cloud from 'd3-cloud';

D3 is working fine but d3 cloud is not loading. When I build using grund, it throws compile time error
Cannot find Module 'd3-cloud'

Package.json:
.....
"d3": "^4.2.6",
"d3-cloud": "^1.2.1",
.....

Any help will be much appreciated and thank you

Answer (score -1):

Forgot to add typings for d3-cloud. Now fixed

Comment: Hi! can you tell me how you added the typings for d3-cloud?