# Angular 4 : properly importing and using d3 and d3-cloud and their typings

Tags: angular, d3.js, import, angular-cli, definitelytyped

I'm trying to use d3 + d3-cloud to make a word cloud with Angular CLI (Angular 4+)

I did an `npm i` of both libraries plus their respective typings :

```
"dependencies": {
    "d3": "^4.10.2",
    "d3-cloud": "^1.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^4.10.0",
    "@types/d3.cloud.layout": "^1.2.32"
  }
```

and Import them in my component :

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import * as cloud from 'd3-cloud'
```

Console logging them in my `ngOnInit` returns instances of both libraries.

the typings for d3 are working (if I type `d3.`I get intellisense) but nothing for `cloud.`

I tried `d3.layout.cloud` but I get a typescript error, I'm guessing I should use `cloud`instead since I've instantiated it this way but since I don't get intellisense I'm not sure.

`cloud.layout.cloud()` results in a `Cannot read property 'cloud' of undefined` error.

I'm confused as to how I should properly import and use d3-cloud and their typings, I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909147/angular-2-cannot-find-module-d3-cloud) but the user never answered the question of how he fixed his problem.

Is my method the right way of using these libraries ?

Answer (score 1):

The installed type definitions for `d3-cloud` seems to be wrong. Install `@types/d3-cloud`.

> npm install @types/d3-cloud --save-dev

That will introduce `d3-cloud` in **package.json** and not `d3.cloud.layout`.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/d3-cloud": "^1.2.2"
}
```

Import d3-cloud along with d3 in your component.

```
import * as cloud from 'd3-cloud';
```

Use this to create layout.

```
render(){
    var layout = cloud().size([width, height])
                        .words(this.data.map(function(d) { return {text: d.name}; }));
    // Misc code
}
```